# How to run a declarative SP Designer workflow using a different account

Tags: sharepoint-designer, workflow, designer-workflow

How to run a Declarative SP Designer workflow using a different account other than the system account.I am not using Workflow Manager in my scenario.

Comment: Check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10737618/run-workflow-with-specified-users-id-in-sharepoint

Comment: which version of SharePoint?

Comment: Am using SP 2013. Am seeing strange behaviour while my SP Designer Workflow. When I run my WF in my rootweb it works fine.But when I try to run on a sub site it does not work, it failed to trigger.Am having December 2013 CU installed.

Answer (score 2):

The basic thing to remember is that declarative workflows (the one’s created by SharePoint Designer) always run impersonating the user who started the workflow

[Declarative Workflows and User Context](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sharepointdesigner/archive/2008/09/28/declarative-workflows-and-user-context.aspx)

in SharePoint designer 2010 microsoft has introducted a concept called impersonation steps where a sections of the workflow can be run under the identity of the person who authored the workflow rather than by the workflow’s initiator. Thus Impersonating the Steps or actions.

[Impersonation in Sharepoint designer 2010 workflow](http://www.learningsharepoint.com/2010/07/31/impersonation-in-sharepoint-designer-2010-workflow/)

In Sharepoint 2013, impersonate step is depecreated and they introduced the App step( new method, which requires you to wrap any actions in your workflow that require elevated permissions in an App Step.).

[APP STEP OR IMPERSONATION STEP IN SHAREPOINT DESIGNER 2013?](http://summit7systems.com/app-step-or-impersonation-step-in-sharepoint-designer-2013/)

[SharePoint Designer 2013 – The new “App Step”](http://www.learningsharepoint.com/2012/12/20/sharepoint-designer-2013-the-new-app-step/)